# iterating over bat script argumets in tuple manner

Tags: batch-file

I need to write a batch script for windows which handle arguments with the structure:

```
one=1 two=2 three=3
```

i'd like to iterate over them in tuples, i.e (psedu):

```
> for %%x,%%y in (%*) do
> 
>     echo param %%x got value %%y
```

I tried nested loop and other ugly hacks, is there a convenient way to get what I need?

Thanks!

Comment: What the hell is a tuple?

Comment: @SomethingDark https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuple

Comment: If a tuple usually has the format `(1,2,3)`, not `one=1 two=2 three=3` then please define specifically the format your arguments are intended to be passed in.

Comment: So it's an array that acts like an object whose values never change? How do you iterate over something "in tuples?"

Comment: Sorry for not being clear, "In tuple manner" means I want my item variable to to hold tuple at every given time.
In each iteration I wanted a tuple of key and value, Aacini did a nice trick. thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "var="
for %%a in (%*) do (
   if not defined var (
      set "var=%%a"
   ) else (
      set "!var!=%%a"
      ECHO "!var!=%%a"
      set "var="
   )
)
```

Output example:

```
C:\> test.bat one=1 two=2 three=3
"one=1"
"two=2"
"three=3"
```

Answer (score 1):

Since cmd.exe will take the equal sign as an argument separator you have to take precautions. Aacini reassembled the pairs, my batch puts quotes around all args and the spaces.

```
@Echo off
Set "Allargs="%*""
For %%A in (%AllArgs: =" "%) Do (
  For /f "tokens=1* delims==" %%x in (%%A) Do echo param %%x got value %%y
)
```

---

```
> test.cmd one=1 two=2 three=3
param one got value 1
param two got value 2
param three got value 3
```

Comment: that would be exactly what I wanted if the variables wouldn't get extra quatation mark, perhaps it's a simple issue? I admit I have not enough experience in batch scripting to fix it.
Thanks for your answer!